# How to sort list with multiple sort keys

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, stl, hash

I am using compare function to sort QList
and MyClass has n different attribute(s) like address, age, firstname, lastname etc

SortKey is something like this.

```
typedef QPair<QString, Qt::SortOrder> SortKeyPair;         
//pair of attr name (i.e. gender and order of sorting asc|desc)


static bool compare( MyClass *o1, MyClass *o2)
{
    //sortKey is global static var.
    if (sortKey.second == Qt::AscendingOrder) {
        if (o1->dataField(sortKey.first) < o2->dataField(sortKey.first)) return true;
        else return false;
    } else {
        if (o1->dataField(sortKey.first) > o2->dataField(sortKey.first)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Sorting by single attr. works fine with qSort.
But I need list sorted with multiple attr. like 'sort by lastname, then by age, then by gender'

I need a sort function to sort by multiple sortKey (which is not working !)

How can we sort with multiple sort keys?
Is there any data structure available that supports this ? (like map always keep things sorted according to key given)

Comment: You cannot sort a hash table, nor a subrange of it. I don’t know how exactly `QHash` is implemented but your request doesn’t seem like a meaningful operation, and in fact `h.values(val)` should return something that’s `const` and cannot be assigned to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define your predicate in the logical way, using the major key for comparison and using the minor key as a fallback when the major is inconclusive:

```
if (o1->dataField( firstSortKey ) < o2->dataField( firstSortKey ))
    return true;
else if (o1->dataField( firstSortKey) > o2->dataField( firstSortKey ))
    return false;
else if ( o1->dataField( secondSortKey ) < o2->dataField( secondSortKey ) )
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

or, for the general case:

```
bool compare_on( int key_index, ...) {
  if (o1->dataField( key[key_index] ) < o2->dataField( key[key_index] ))
    return true;
  else if (o1->dataField( key[key_index] ) > o2->dataField( key[key_index] ))
    return false;
  else if ( key_index == max_key_index )
    return false;
  else
    return compare_on( key_index + 1 );
```

Comment: This solution is trivial. What if we have n keys ?

Comment: @smitpatel24: Then you need more if's. This means iterating on the list of sort keys, best by recursion. Added a snippet.

Comment: @thiton There are only a few things done "best by recursion" and this simple for loop surely is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::tuple (or boost::tuple for older C++03) to do this comparison in one line:

```
return make_tuple(a.lastname, a.age, a.gender) < make_tuple(b.lastname, b.age, b.gender);
```

Comment: In my case number of keys varies, so this may not be a good idea. But still easiest solution. :)